# How to make an arrow in html5 or css

Tags: css, html

i want to use an arrow similar to the ones in this web page http://9gag.tv/v/2753 to navigate through my web page, anyone know how it's made?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=html5+draw+shapes&oq=html5+draw+shapes&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2675j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: What browser do you use? Maybe if you switch to another one, you can just inspect the code of the page.

Comment: its a png sprite. Search create sprite tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it using css to avoid loading an image:

```
    <a href="#" id="left"></a>

    #left {
    display: block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 40px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

    #left:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 39px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 39px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 39px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -39px;
    left: 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LtFnR/1/

Answer (score 2):

The page you mention uses the following image: http://d1nmj8esheg8s6.cloudfront.net/build/1389597552/img/video-nav-sprite.png as sprite. That means: it displays part of it at a time, depending on the conditions.
Relevant CSS:

```
.stage .next:hover .icon {
    background: url("../img/video-nav-sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -34px -68px transparent;
}
.stage .next .icon {
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
    background: url("../img/video-nav-sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -34px 0px transparent;
}
```

pay attention to ":hover" pseudo-selector and to different offset within an image (background attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You may take a simple CSS solution but won´t work in older Browsers.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GLORIEN/ja84a/)

```
<span class="arrow"></span>


.arrow {
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-color:black;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;

}
```